# Can't skip Doorkeeper auth for create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, doorkeeper

I'm trying to create a user account on my app via an API. At the top of my API controller I added an exception to doorkeeper_for so that create could be run by somebody with a token:

`doorkeeper_for :all, unless: :create`

When I call the API though I get a 401 error and a message that the token is invalid. Clearly it's ignoring the unless: exception. Any ideas why?

Comment: Do you try to reproduce some old screencast? Because I cannot find method doorkeeper_for in github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper right now. There's only before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!, except: :create.

Comment: I was learning from screencasts but doorkeeper_for is working as the rest of my API is authenticating properly. I will check this out tonight though, thanks!

Comment: @yukke Seems to be working. I'm getting a 422 now but the auth problem is gone. If you make that comment into an answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to reproduce some old screencast. Because I cannot find method doorkeeper_for in [gem doorkeeper](http://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper) right now. There's only:

```
before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!, except: :create
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is actually correct. doorkeeper_authorize! is part of doorkeeper v2.0 which isn't released yet. I eventually went back to doorkeeper_for and got it working.